# WinAPI resize breaks minwidth/minheight... how do I fix this?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a WPF window that I've made borderless. I've coded the resize/drag functionality using WinAPI, but it ignores the minwidth and minheight of the window. How do I enforce these values?

My code is as follows:

```
private void Resize(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    String resizeHandle = (sender as System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle).Name;

    ResizeDirection direction = 
            resizeHandle == "PART_RESIZEHANDLE_TOP" ? ResizeDirection.Top
          : resizeHandle == "PART_RESIZEHANDLE_BOTTOM" ? ResizeDirection.Bottom
          : resizeHandle == "PART_RESIZEHANDLE_LEFT" ? ResizeDirection.Left
          : resizeHandle == "PART_RESIZEHANDLE_RIGHT" ? ResizeDirection.Right
          : resizeHandle == "PART_RESIZEHANDLE_TOPLEFT" ? ResizeDirection.TopLeft
          : resizeHandle == "PART_RESIZEHANDLE_TOPRIGHT" ? ResizeDirection.TopRight
          : resizeHandle == "PART_RESIZEHANDLE_BOTTOMLEFT" ? ResizeDirection.BottomLeft
          : resizeHandle == "PART_RESIZEHANDLE_BOTTOMRIGHT" ? ResizeDirection.BottomRight 
          : 0;

    if (direction == ResizeDirection.Unknown)
        throw new ArgumentException();

    SendMessage(hwndSource.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, (IntPtr)(61440 + direction), IntPtr.Zero);

}

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, uint Msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
```

Comment: Hard to believe this code could work at all.  Override the processing of the WM_NCHITTEST message instead.  Google "wpf and wm_nchittest"

Comment: I've tried this, with the same results. The window can be resized below the minimum height/width.